# opencart tax rate function 1.5.6

Tags: php, opencart

Does someone know how to get the tax rate in Opencart 1.5.6.

It should be `$string = $this->tax->getRate($tax_class_id);` but that was depreciated. When I get the taxrate from config  `$this->config->get('config_tax');` I only get the tax ID

Is there a way to get the current tax rate build in opencart or has that to be done by using `$this->config->get('config_tax')` and a new function?

Hope some one can give me a clue

Comment: Surely the tax rate depends on the product, tax rate and jurisdiction? Then there is import/export taxes. This is a legal minefield and you will not get for free

Answer (score 0):

`$this->config->get('config_tax')` is used to determine if you want to apply tax rates to your items at all (simply an on-off switch if you like).

1.5.6 is no different to most of the 1.5.X series in that you get tax. Tax rates can also be multiple not just one, so `getRates()` will return an array of values. You call it using `$this->tax->getRates($price_value, $tax_class_id)` and it will return all of the tax associated with that. However, you really shouldn't be calling that directly, you should be calling the `$this->tax->calculate($price, $tax_class_id, $this->config->get('config_tax'))` to correctly determine tax values on a price.

For reference, you should check out the file `/system/library/tax.php` if you haven't already for the full tax methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay. I need the tax rate only (21%, 6% etc) because I want to do some calculations with that rate. I'll try to figure out how to use getRates() and $this->tax->getRates($price_value, $tax_class_id)

Comment: You should be able to reverse the tax based on the tax amount and the input value to work out the original rate for that (might need to round the value slightly)